# Add 0 to value of input of type number

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to increase the number of 0 when I change the value of my input but everytime I trigger the function the value is reset. The same thing happens if I want to decrease it. I don't know if it's possible but I have to block the auto increment of the last number when I click on "up" and "down" and replace it by 0 incrementation. Maybe I could use a mask ?

example :

up :
123 -> 0123 -> 00123

down :
00123 -> 0123 -> 123

TS

```
  pad() {
    //if the actual count if bigger than the old one
    if (this.count > this.value) {
      //add a 0 to the count
      this.count  = '0' + this.count;
    } else {
      //remove the first character of the count
      this.count.toString().substring(1);
    }
    //take the last value of the count
    this.value = this.count;
  }
```

Input

```
  <input type="number" min="0" name="count" [(ngModel)]="count" (change)="pad()" />
```

Comment: Why do you use string ? you know that `'0' + '1'` = '01'` right ? What is `this.value` ? Also not really sure what you are trying to do with `this.count = 0 + this.count` even if you use number type :( . Please be more specific about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Yes, I know but I didn't find any other way to add 0 and `this.value` is just a property to keep the old value of the count.

Comment: Hi, I am not completely understanding. Are you wanting, each time the user increments a count, to add another 0 to the front of the string, and every time they decrease the count to remove a 0?

Comment: Yes, but i think I will have to use something else than input number because I don't want to increment the count on change. Like 2 different buttons. @AHaworth

Comment: How about using the input type=number but overwriting it (visually, not in the actual element) with the string you actually want the user to see? That way you could use the input's native increment facility but show the user what you want to show them.

Comment: I can give a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a JS solution, I don't think this is optimized but it works

TS

```
  addZero() {
    var stringZero = '0';
    var zeroToAdd = stringZero.repeat(1);
    this.array.push(zeroToAdd);
    if (this.array.length < 10) {
      this.count = zeroToAdd + this.count;
      parseInt(this.count);
    }
  }

  removeZero() {
    var stringCount = this.count.toString();
    if (stringCount.length > 1 && stringCount.charAt(0) == 0) {
      this.count = stringCount.substring(1);
      parseInt(this.count);
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<button  type="button" (click)="addZero()"></button>
<button  type="button" (click)="removeZero()"></button>
```